# How can i describe table in cassandra database?

Tags: cql

```
$describe = new Cassandra\SimpleStatement(<<<EOD
             describe keyspace.tablename
EOD
    );
    $session->execute($describe);
```

i used above code but it is not working.
how can i fetch field name and it's data type from Cassandra table ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Refer to CQL documentation. Describe expects a table/schema/keyspace.

`describe table keyspace.tablename`

Its also a cqlsh command, not an actual cql command. To get this information query the system tables. try

```
select * from system.schema_columns;

- or for more recent versions -

select * from system_schema.columns ;
```

if using php driver may want to check out http://datastax.github.io/php-driver/features/#schema-metadata

Answer (score 0):

Try `desc table keyspace.tablename;`

Comment: @Vijay: Your query doesn't work with with DevCenter. Can you please share minimum requirements to run this query?

Comment: It is not really a good answer - because it explains nothing. But it works. 
Login (using cqlsh) and from the root you can do `desc table {keyspace}.[table}`
Or, login to your keyspace: use {keyspace}, then `desc table {table}` will suffice